# What does 'I know what's right but that can get me' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, lyrics

I was listening to a music Ori Rose - A.S.A.G.

I couldn't get the meaning of what 'I know what's right but that can get me.'.
I searched for the meaning of 'get me', but I found out it has a lot of meanings depends on where it's used.

Therefore what does that sentence mean? and 'get me' mean inside that sentence?

--- Lyrics ---

> I'm sorry bout the crazy shit I told you last night
>
> Last girl left me in the dark without a flashlight
>
> Now I got this paranoia inside me
>
> Worried that it’s slowly slowly driving you away and
>
> That’s my bad you should correct me
>
> I know what’s right but that can ***get me*** cuz,
>
> Sometimes I act like a lefty
>
> but you still by my side so

Answer (score 1):

Generally, this meaning of "get me" is something like "affect me in a strong way, unexpectedly".

> *I'm normally easygoing, but screaming children really get me.*

Here, it means screaming children irritate me a lot, where other things generally don't.

> *Titanic is a terrible movie, but when Jack dies, it gets me every time.*

Here, it means I don't like the movie Titanic, but the scene where Jack dies makes me feel very sad.

In A.S.A.G., "get me" means "make me feel paranoid".

Answer (score 0):

Song lyrics can be difficult to analyze since the artist often compromises clarity in order to fit the structure of a song but I'll give it a shot. Basically, he's saying that he knows what is right, implying he should do what is right, but also recognizing that doing what is right might not work out to his benefit and 'get him'.

Often 'to get someone' simply means to understand them well, but in the context of the full song I don't think it fits.